# How do I define a group of attributes to reuse in empty and non-empty elements?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to define a schema that supports elements like this:

```
<one att1="foo" att2="bar"/>
<two att1="foo" att2="bar">TEXT</two>
<three att1="Foo" att2="bar" att3="baz"/>
```

How do I define a type hierarchy to encompass att1 and att2?

```
<complexType name="Att">
    <attribute name="att1" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="att2" type="string"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="One">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:Att"/>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>


<complexType name="Two">
    <simpleContent>
        <extension base="tns:Att"/>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="Three">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="tns:Att">
            <attribute name="att3" type="string"/>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

That doesn't work for Two, and I get errors about extending complexContent with simpleContent

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<complexType name="Att" mixed="true">
    <attribute name="att1" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="att2" type="string"/>
</complexType>

...

<complexType name="Two">
    <simpleContent>
        <restriction base="tns:Att">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="string"/>
            </simpleType>
        </restriction>
    </simpleContent>
</complexType>
```